# Coefficients in Gaussian polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions, formal-power-series

Let
$$
\binom{n}{k}_{\!q} = \frac{(1-q^n) \cdots (1-q^{n-k+1})}{(1-q) \cdots (1-q^k)}
$$
be the Gaussian polynomials. For example,
$$
\binom{6}{3}_{\!q} = 1+q+2q^2+3q^3+3q^4+3q^5+3q^6+2q^7+q^8+q^9.
$$
It seems that the coefficients in $\binom n k _q$ are always weakly increasing up to $q^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}$, where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial. How would one prove this?

If $p_{k\ell}(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ that fit into an $k\times\ell$-rectangle, I know that $\sum_np_{k\ell}(n)q^n=\binom{k+\ell}{\ell}_q$ (generating functions), so it seems reasonable to try to find an injection from the set of partitions counted by $p_{k\ell}(n)$ to the set of partitions counted by $p_{k\ell}(n+1)$, where $n\leq\lfloor k\ell/2\rfloor$, but I cannot find such an injection.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer there giving the major details of what I think is the most elegant proof, plus some links to other proofs, so I will close this as a duplicate.